# Edit highlighting seems incorrect

Tags: bug, editing, edit-history

I believe the color highlighting [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3833317/revisions) should be showing that the third formula
$$\implies (\alpha-\beta ) z+\beta (\bar z +z) + \gamma - \alpha \bar z = 0$$
was changed to
$$\implies (\alpha-\beta ) z+\beta (\bar z +z) + \gamma = 0.$$
Instead, the highlighting looks like this:
[image]